# Openerp remove a submenu

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I want to hide/remove "Timesheet Activities" from the "Human Resource" module. I thought assigning it to a different group would do the trick but it doesn't seem to work.

This is what I have in my custom security.xml:

```
    <record id="timesheet_activities" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Timesheet Activities</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_hidden"/>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add group on menu *Timesheet Activities*

Go to *Setting => Technical => User Interface => Menu items => and find out "Timesheet Activities"* add it with new group created.

[image: Timesheet Activities in Odoo]

Comment: In your question, you created a security group which will come in it. If you click *Add an item*, you may added your new group. Based on that group you can give access right to the User. If User with *Timesheet Activities* checked, than Menu is visible for that User.

Answer (score 0):

Create new group and add only Administrator to this group and assign that group to the any menus. So the only admin can see the menus for all other it will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it from backend then just overwrite the menu in your custom module and add the new group in that menu section

Answer (score 0):

Create a `group` named like `Hidden Items`,

```
<record model="res.groups" id="group_invisible">
    <field name="name">Hidden items</field>
    <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
</record>
```

And add that menu into this group,

```
  <record id="module_name.menuitem_name" model="ir.ui.menu">
        <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, False, [ref('module_name.group_invisible')])]"/>
  </record>
```

Hope it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<delete model="ir.ui.menu" id="hr.your_menu_id"/>
```